# How to use Using enum RelationshipType with Neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I would like to define some relationship type between some typed node. When I look example always they use a String to define relationship type, as [in this example](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/developer-resources/blob/gh-pages/language-guides/java/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/java/movies/spring/data/neo4j/domain/Role.java) . By using:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "ACTED_IN")
```

I tried to use org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType but RelationshipEntity.type expect a string.

```
public enum PersonMovieRelationshipType implements RelationshipType {
    ACTED_IN("ACTED_IN"),
    AUTHOR("AUTHOR");

    private String type;

    PersonMovieRelationshipType( String type ){
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

RelationshipType enum provide a method "name()" what to do with ?

I do not like free text way, is it possible use an enum ?

Any full example will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Unfortunately Enums don't work with Object instances. And you would also have to implement .name() for your class.

Comment: Enums would be possible in theory but then you could only allow one enum globally across all projects which kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Is this comment still valid? According to a post by Luanne from July 2016 "As long as you have an enum we can recognize, meaning it’s scanned with your domain packages, we will automatically convert the enum to a string property, store it on your node and convert it back to your enum when you load the entity from the graph." (https://neo4j.com/blog/spring-data-neo4j-4-1-applications/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't due to the way annotations work. What you could do is declaring the relation names as constants.

```
interface RelationNames{
  String ACTED_IN = "ACTED_IN";
}
```

And then use those constants in your code

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = RelationNames.ACTED_IN)
```

Comment: I'd second that, but I would recommend using a final class with a private default constructor if it's only purpose if to hold constants...

Comment: @SamuelKerrien valid pt, some people consider it an anti-pattern, I am not  entirely convinced though :)